# Change format of date with PHP

Tags: php, date-format

I want to change this date format: "Tue Apr 3 15:00:03 GMT+0300 2012" to "3.4.2012" with PHP. Is it possible?

I tried:

```
$date="Tue Apr 3 15:00:03 GMT+0300 2012";
echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime($date));
```

but it results in: `03.04.2015`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: I've run this on PHP 5.3.18 (Fedora 14) and it gives the correct results, what are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date is not formatted correctly, at least it is not the RFC 2822 date format,

```
Tue, 3 Apr 2012 15:00:03 +0300
```

`strtotime` is quite flexible but it cannot guess what you mean ...

Comment: strtotime can take in tons of Date/Time formats. It doesn't have to be RFC 2822: http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Comment: yes, but it looks like that RFC 2822 is the format he's trying to use

Comment: its an actionscript format that i want to transfer in a web page..What i finally did is to split it and give it into date() as one of the formats accepted by php so the date() now knows how to convert it.

Answer (score 4):

[Read the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) before using a function, and especially before asking other people to read it for you, like I just did to answer your question:

```
date('j.n.Y', strtotime($date));
```

[**Codepad Example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/K3s1Pv)

Comment: i think his problem is the incorrect year and not the leading zeroes

Comment: I think that the problem in his case, is that strtotime() is not parsing the date string properly and not the leading zeros of day/month.

Comment: @scibuff Pretty sure it's the leading zeros. strtotime has no trouble parsing that date: http://codepad.viper-7.com/K3s1Pv I think the 2015 in the OP is just a typo

Comment: @mobius See response to scibuff

Comment: @PaulP.R.O it does not work for me and the possible fact is that it does not accept the format. You could not answer if you didnt want to. And just to know, there are no silly questions just silly answers...